# Can this curve be parametrized by a $C^{\infty}$ map

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

Can the curve defined by $t \mapsto (t,|t|)$ be parametrized by a $C^{\infty}$ map?

I understand there is an issue at the origin because it is not smooth, but I wonder if this is enough to ensure that any parametrization will not be continuously differentiable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $g(t)=\begin{cases} e^{-1/t^2}, & t\ne 0 \\ 0, & t=0 \end{cases}$. Consider the parametrization $f(t) = g(t)(t,|t|)$. You can check this function is smooth — you have all derivatives $0$ at $0$, so you round the corner *extremely* slowly.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I expected

Comment: I should have commented that this is not technically a parametrization (since the derivative is not always nonzero). But it is a smooth bijection to the curve.